# Windows 10 Widget Menu

Tags: windows-10, widgets

I've got a windows 10 (desktop) with the german language activated. While I left the room and came back suddenly a semi transparent menu popped up which was called "windows widget menu". It showed my cpu in one widget and other data in others. Looked cool but I never started that consciously, nor installed anything that has widgets, ...  also it was interestingly in english.

Now my question is: Is that an automatic part of windows 10 and how can I show that menu again? (as I did not find anything about it in the search nor on google).

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/widget-launcher/9wzdncrdqfbt#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: @user1292580 yepp that looks quite simliar to what I saw (only called weidget menu there). why does that pop up all of a sudden without user interaction? (and never installed that consciously)

Comment: I don't know. You must have I suppose. Note it is not an MS product. It is also 8 years old and installing it is linked to your MS account. So you may have installed in the last **eight (8) years** on another machine. Note it has had yearly updates since then.

Comment: @user1292580 wemy is correct with the statement that win +g triggers what I'm seeing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those widgets are part of the Xbox Game bar that is installed by default.

I don't know how it can activate itself, but you can show that menu again by pressing <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-problems-with-xbox-game-bar-on-windows-10-74a718a1-2fbf-2ce3-5fbe-e959be352277